# Facebook photos not showing up on lock screen

Tags: facebook, lock-screen

I want my phone to show Facebook photos on the lock screen but it just shows a blue screen with the Facebook logo. It used to work so I don't know what has changed. How can I get it working again?

Comment: have you tried reinstalling the Facebook app? have you recently installed any (OS) updates?

Comment: Yep - I think it must be some setting I've got wrong - maybe on fb. It started on my old phone - 520 - then got a new 530, restored all my settings etc from the old phone and this transferred to the new phone. Thanks for your help, this is driving me crazy!

Comment: Just a wild guess, but check your Facebook privacy settings. Sometimes apps can't get the data they request because those are too strict.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after Denim-upgrade. I have Lumia 820 with memory card & had transferred my Facebook there. I uninstalled it and downloaded it back to my phone memory. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when Facebook is moved to the SD card. I just moved it back to phone memory and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -5):

no to all that. settings-> lock screen-> set background to Facebook photos or something else. the end

Comment: How I've read the question; that's what littleskate has done, but it's not working, and your answer doesn't include any details of things to try if it doesn't work?